# How to fill the space between the grid lines with multiple colours in JpGraph?

Tags: php, colors, linegraph, jpgraph

So alternating two colours between grid lines using the SetFill function is simple enough, however, I need 7 different colours in my line graph.

```
$graph->ygrid->SetFill(true,'red','blue', [5 more colours etc] );
```

At the moment I have tried adding more parameters to the SetFill function in jpgrapgh.php without success. See code example below:

```
function SetFill($aFlg=true,$aColor1='lightgray',$aColor2='lightblue',$aColor3='darkblue') {

    $this->fill = $aFlg;
    $this->fillcolor = array( $aColor1, $aColor2, $aColor3);
}
```

I suspect more scripts need updating to cater for this change?

Answer (score 0):

This solution allows you to keep the alternation option, but when you pass in more colours (7 in my case), it fills the space between the grid lines with the colour passed in.

```
$graph->ygrid->SetFill(true,'red','orange','orange','green','orange','orange','red');
```

Update the SetFill function to read:

```
function SetFill($aFlg=true,$aColor1='lightgray',$aColor2='lightblue',$aColor3=null,$aColor4=null,$aColor5=null,$aColor6=null,$aColor7=null) {
    $this->fill = $aFlg;
    $this->fillcolor = array( $aColor1, $aColor2, $aColor3, $aColor4, $aColor5, $aColor6, $aColor7 );
    $this->fillcolor = array_filter($this->fillcolor);
}
```

And within the DoStroke function update:

```
            // If we have passed in 7 colours
            if(count($this->fillcolor)==7) {

                // Loop out all 7 the colours
                while ($i < $nbrgrids) {
                    $this->img->SetColor($this->fillcolor[$i - 1]); // Offset by 1 because array keys start at 0
                    $y1 = $y2;
                    $y2 = $aTicksPos[$i++];
                    $this->img->FilledRectangle($xl, $y1, $xr, $y2);
                }

            } else {

                // Otherwise, do the normal alternation loop
                while ($i < $nbrgrids) {
                    $y1 = $y2;
                    $y2 = $aTicksPos[$i++];
                    $this->img->SetColor($this->fillcolor[$i & 1]);
                    $this->img->FilledRectangle($xl, $y1, $xr, $y2);
                }
            }
```